# Velocity: Get key and value from JSON

Tags: json, velocity

I have a JSON file like so...

```
{
 "template" : "test-template",
 "url" : "url",
 "imageCount" : 4,
 "pageSize" : 36,
 "class" : "test-class"
}
```

Now I know I can access individual parameters. Accessing `$template` will print `test-template` for example.

Is there a way to iterate through the entire collection and get both the keys and the values?

Comment: Maybe you can use ContextTool for this? If not, add a tool to the same effect to the context. https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/summary.html

Answer (score 4):

```
#foreach($key in $json.keySet())
  <div>$key : $json.get($key)</div>
#end
```

Comment: Best answer. Self explanatory. Will make an update to this answer to explain it though,..

Answer (score 2):

1. You can create a custom uberspector by extending class SecureUberspector and override method getIterator for JsonObject (use instance of operator).
2. Create an iterator Class by implementing interface Iterator. Use the fact that some Json implantations have keys() method which return Iterator ,Others have entrySet() method which returns               Set < Entry < String, JsonObject>>.

refer link : http://ajdevtech.blogspot.in/2016/02/blog-post.html